# elaticsearch monitoring search queries

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, logstash

For more than a week I am struggling with trying to log into an index in elasticsearch information regarding queries which I run so I could compare performance between different types of queries. I have configured this config file on logstash home directory

```
    input { 
    beats { 
        port> 5044
      }
}
filter {
    if "search" in [request]{
        grok {
            match => { "request" => ".*\n\{(?<query_body>.*)"} 
            }
        grok {
            match => { "path" => "\/(?<index>.*)\/_search"}     
            }
     if [index] {
      } else {
            mutate {
              add_field  => { "index" => "All" }
        }
      }
      mutate {
              update  => { "query_body" => "{%{query_body}" }
      }
   }
}
output {
  if "search" in [request] and "ignore_unmapped" not in [query_body]{
        elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
        }
   }
}
```

and also installed and configured packetbeat.yml 
logstash hosts to :http://localhost:9200

Also in the tutorial that I have followed is mentioned that after starting Packetbeat it will listen for packets on 9200 sending them to Logstash and from there to the monitoring Elasticsearch cluster, it will be indexed in indexes like: logstash-2016.05.24. But these indexes does not exists.

Comment: so, what kind of error you have?

Comment: would you be able to tell us how can we reproduce your error? it will be great if you can add more details.